# GitLab Container Registry Not Updating Docker Container Layers

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers

I have a Docker build environment where I build containers locally and test them.  When I'm done, I push them to our Dev GitLab container registry to be deployed to Kubernetes.

I've run into a situation where either Docker isn't pushing up the newest layers or GitLab is seeing layers from a previous version and just mounting that layer so when the container is deployed in Kubernetes, the container, despite the new tag, is running the old container image.

I've tried completely wiping my Docker image repository, rebuilding, and repushing and that didn't fix it.  I tried using the red trash icon in GitLab to delete the old version of the tag I'm trying to use.

I added some echo's in the console output for the container so I know the new bits aren't being run but I can't figure out if the problem is Docker or GitLab or how to fix it.  Anyone have any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: There's not much to go on here. Please provide some steps to reproduce, and commands+output showing the issues you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard -- my workers had a docker image on them and because my imagePullPolicy in my YAML was not set, it was defaulting to using the cached image in Docker.  I just had to clear the image on my worker node (`docker rmi -f <image name>`) and then I updated my deployment YAML to use an `imagePullPolicy: Always`.